# Unable to execute cordova

Tags: apache, node.js, mobile, ant, cordova

I was able to install cordova originally but I am now unable to use it.
I have uninstalled using npm uninstall -g cordova, and this seems to be working as expected. When I attempt to reinstall it using the command npm install -g cordova, the installation seems to run, but when attempting to run cordova commands I get the cordova is not a recognized internal or external batch command message. This is on a Windows 7 Pro x64 machine. What could be the possible causes and fixes for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you already had the apacha ant ready? If not, try to download that from apache.org and put the patch folder where you extract this to your path variable.

Comment: Ant is pulled down but when I attempt to execute it from the Command Prompt it says that it cannot locate the tools.jar file. I assume this is a Environment Variable issue as well. What java folder needs to be set up as the PATH variable to let this build?

Comment: I added it to the correct folder and now it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the cordova installation path folder to you path environment variables

Comment: Do you know where these files may be? I keep searching but I think my Google is broken or I am just not using the correct terms.